# how to access the request object in the scala template

Tags: playframework

I have a controller which I have marked with @With

```
@With(InitPages.class)
public class Application extends Controller {

    public static Result index() {

        return ok(mainpage.render());
        //return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready."));
    }

}
```

this InitPages class is doing the following:

```
public class InitPages extends Action.Simple {

    public Result call(Http.Context ctx) throws Throwable {

        List<CustomPage> pages = CustomPage.find.all();
        ctx.args.put("pages", pages);

        Logger.info("Calling action for " + ctx);
        return delegate.call(ctx);
    }
}
```

I want to put the "pages" variable in the scala template, what is the correct way of doing it?
The Play Framework in its documentation describe it should be done like this, ergo putting the objects in the request map, but how could I display it in the scala template?

I tried different versions of this:

```
@for(page <- request.pages) {
   <li class="parent"> <a href="#sds"> @page.title </a> </li>
}
```

and

```
@for(page <- pages) {
   <li class="parent"> <a href="#sds"> @page.title </a> </li>
}
```

but with no luck
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaActionsComposition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not used the Java version of Play 2.0, only Scala, but there are a couple of areas where I feel you may have an error (I may be wrong):

- Usually the request object (unless you extended it somehow, if so please attach the code), doesn't have a "pages" member. You may want to call method `get("pages")`
- Pages is added to Context, but you try to retrieve it from request. Are they equivalent? Did you copy the data somehow? Or what you need to do is to access the Response object?

Comment: hi, thanks for reply. When you go to the HTTP object which Play provides you see this:

/** 
         * Free space to store your request specific data
         */
        public Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>(16);

Comment: So thats where I want to store my Pages List. "pages" is just a variable containing a list with my own CustomPages objects

List<CustomPage> pages = CustomPage.find.all();

Your second point, yes, your are right, my fault, I want to access args, not request. But in the bigger picture I really want to access the field variables in the HTTP class which Play provides me. Cant figure out how to do this when play required me to explicitly provde my objects to the scala template.